# same selector in every level users doesn't working in the first time

Tags: jquery

i'm working on in cms which has 3 level users for **update images**

1. ADMIN (One page)
2. Manager(same page cause only images,name,etc with employee just use session)
3. Employee (same page)

which every level user has update foto profile with this button

```
<button type="button" id="btnsubmitprofileimages" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

first minute by testing for **EMPLOYEE** working fine so just copy and paste in every level, then i leave and continue another task then testing in level Manager why it give me errors alert but in my console is clean

this is my whole js

```
$('#btnsubmitprofileimages').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   var imgVal = $('.cropit-image-input').val();
if(imgVal=='') 
        { 
             $("#errors-image-modal").show();
        }
        else
        {       
e.preventDefault();
var imageData = $('.image-editor').cropit('export');
var cu_id_employee=$("input[name=cu_id_employee]").val(); 
var cu_foto_employee_old=$("input[name=cu_foto_employee_old]").val(); 
var data = 'imageData=' + imageData + '&cu_id_employee=' + cu_id_employee+ '&cu_foto_employee_old=' + cu_foto_employee_old;
         $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "userdataajax/updateprofilepictureallemployee",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
        if (data.status) {
                alert('data tersimpan');
                 $('#myModalfoto').modal('hide'); 
                    $('#formfoto').trigger("reset"); 
                     location.reload();
                 } else {
                   alert('error hubungi admin');
                }
                $('#btnsubmitprofileimages').text('save'); //change button text
                $('#btnsubmitprofileimages').attr('disabled', false); //set button enable
              },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error adding / update data');
                $('#btnsubmitprofileimages').text('save'); //change button text
                $('#btnsubmitprofileimages').attr('disabled', false); //set button enable
            }
        });
    }

})
```

Only working in the level **EMPLOYEE**, then i decide to change id in every level **ADMIN**

```
<button type="button" id="btnsubmitprofileimagesadmin" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

now all working fine, but don't know why sometime in level Manager and Employee got erros in the first time, after that they working fine ? what do i miss in this isssue

Note : I know id is uniq cannot double but page in level Manager and Employee is same, is that problem or what, Thanks